# Where does the space go? (VirtualBox VM)

Tags: virtualbox

Sorry, I am not a professional. I need to use a virtual machine with Linux and a lot of disk space. When I created a VM in VirtualBox, I set virtual hard drive size to 80GB. But the system in the VM tells me that I have only 5GB of free space. Obviously, I just started, I did not download anything. When I go to settings I see the hard drive with 80GB. How do I access it?

Comment: You've provided no specifics as to what Ubuntu product, and what release of that product you installed & are thus asking about. Desktop systems have higher requirements than Server systems, but you've given no clues as to what you installed. If using a Server/Core system, you'll use terminal to explore settings, if using a Desktop system you can also use terminal, or have GUI options too - but we haven't been told what you actually installed.  *Also note:  with multiple installers available for different products, plus various options, you may not have yet utilized all disk space too*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that you're booting off of an Ubuntu ISO file, then that's the equivalent of booting a physical computer off of a USB drive or CD/DVD disc - the resulting booted-up system will have its root filesystem living on the USB drive (ISO file), but will be able to see the hard drive in order to install to it.

To do work beyond a one-time task on a VM, you'll need to start your VM from the ISO (which it sounds like you've already done) and then run the installation program (as opposed to "Try Ubuntu" on startup) to install Ubuntu to the virtual hard drive.

Once it's installed, then you can reboot the VM and begin using it as you'd need (installing programs, saving files, etc.).

Hope this helps